# How to find Inner Join in SQLite Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, join, android-sqlite, inner-join

I have two table

table 1(t1)

```
mid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
Name TEXT
```

table 2(t2)

```
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
mid INTEGER
Amount INT
Token TEXT NOT NULL
```

I need a new table which join both these table based on the token value.

New Table

mid Amount Name Token.

My Answer:

```
 String Sql_Query="SELECT t1.Name, t2.Amount, t2.mid, t2.Token from t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON  t1.mid = t2.mid where t2.Token="abc" ";

 db.rawQuery(Sql_Query,null);
```

End up getting empty array.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. If anyone needs solution he/she can use below code

db.rawquery("SELECT t1.Name, t2.Amount, t2.mid, t2.Token from t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON  t1.mid = t2.mid",null);